# Using an old router as a secondary access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have recently acquired a new router and wish to extend my "WiFi coverage" by utilizing my old router as another access point somewhere in the house.

I have followed a number of tutorials and i'm fairly sure I have configured the old router correctly, but do not know how to 'essentially connect to it' as a connection.

This is what I have done, correct me if it is wrong please!
My old router is a Belkin N1, which has a AP mode within the router settings:

- Changed the SSID to that of my new router
- Changed the security to match my new router
- Changed the default IP address to one that lies not within the DHCP from my other router.
- Enabled AP Mode (disabling DHCP), with default gateway being my new router
- This is wired to the new router through the client ports on the back of each router (not the modem)

It seems to be showing up within my network as it should (see attached picture of NETGEARgenie - it has the ip 192.168.0.111).

**How can I actually connect to this though?** 
I am monitoring network strength in a room that is quite lacklustre with the new router and have positioned the old router(now AP) in the same room! and am not getting any strength change!!

I'm not sure if I'm missing something really simple at the end which has to do with specifying which 'gateway' to connect to on the machine i'm using (a macbook pro).

Any help would be appreciated.
(Don't have enough rep for images-feel free to attach!)
**Currently:**
[image]

**How I want it:**
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Have a seperate SSID for the old router, makes it easier to work out when things are not quite right. I have a hunch that its somehow getting confused between the old and new router, and connects to the new one cause its connected before, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I changed the name, but I can't even see it showing up at all - on any device. Would it be likely a problem with the old router itself?

Comment: That sounds very likely then.

Comment: And after using a different SSID for testing, switch back to the same SSID, but *change to a different channel* (and make sure channels don't overlap, google for the distance you need). Two APs talking on the same or overlapping channel(s) will slow everything down instead of speeding it up.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the networks share SSIDs and encryption details (Assuming WPA(2) Personal (aka PSK)) clients will typically roam to the AP with the higher RSSI (Signal Strength).

Tools like inSSIDer, Network Stumbler, and Kismet can be used to view different access points in a single network.